# User switching option has disappeared after installing SP1 (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, user-accounts

Basically, my Switch User button has disappeared from the Shut Down menu after installing SP1 under Windows 7 Ultimate.

I've tried some of the workarounds I've seen posted online, namely changing some Registry values, to no avail.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning I'm running a fresh and clean Windows 7 installation.

Comment: Good, the reason I ask is you have more tools to try, especially `gpedit.msc`, rather than having to do it all in the registry with the home versions.

Answer (score 1):

Try this: Start>Run>type gpedit.msc and hit enter. Navigate to Computer Configuration>Administrative Templates>System>Logon and disable "Hide entry points for Fast User Switching". You will probably have to reboot.

Comment: Already tried that, still not working. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you meant gpedit.msc by the way.

Comment: @fmartin Have you gone to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System and actually deleted the HideFastUserSwitching key? Does it exist on your system, and if so, what is the value it is set to?

Comment: @KCotreau It didn't exist at first. I then created it and set it to 0.

Comment: One more thing you could try is right click on the taskbar and go to properties. Click on the middle "Start Menu" tab, and set the "Power button action" to "Switch user" (restart if necessary). Then change it back and see if the menu item reappears.

Comment: Did creating it and rebooting fix it?

Comment: @fmartin let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/593/discussion-between-kcotreau-and-fmartin)

Comment: No, I tried that before asking this here. "Switch User" doesn't show up on "Power button action"'s options.

Answer (score 0):

Add another user in Control Panel / User accounts. Or if you are sure there are already multiple users that they are not all disabled. Windows 7 default is to have the Administrator account disabled, but if you boot in safe-mode you can select that user account. Many people forget to set a password on this account which leaves them a little vulnerable to someone making serious changes without your permission.

Comment: Nope, there's already 4 user accounts set up.